# How to compare the value of a phrase within a table with a letter?

Tags: c

I need to create a function that is given a table with different phrases and I must print the first phrase on the table that ends in "n". How would I go about this?

So far I have the table with three phrases with the second one ending in "n". Ive tried different things for the last hour but I'm new to C and it is tricky.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef char  TTablaFrases[5][80]; //una tabla de 10 frases

int FraseAcabadaEnN (TTablaFrases tabla)
{
    
}

int main(void) {
    
    TTablaFrases miTabla;
    
    strcpy (miTabla[0], "First phrase");
    strcpy (miTabla[1], "Second phrase n");
    strcpy (miTabla[2], "Third phrase");
    
}
```

Comment: Tip: Normally C code is written like `strcpy(x, y)`  not `strcpy (x, y)`. The extra space is very distracting. In most C code that's used for constructs like `if (...)` or `while (...)`.

Comment: Hint: `strlen()`.

Comment: Loop through the array. Test if the last character of the current phrase is `n`. If so, print the phrase and break out of the loop.

Comment: You need to pass in a size of your table.

Comment: Do the strings`"abcn    "` (with trailing whitespace) or `"abcn."` (with trailing punctuation) end in `n`?  If not, just use `strrchr` to find the index of the last `n` in the string and check if the next character is `\0`.  If so, add some logic to discard characters that you don't care about.

Comment: @tadman Some coding standards (like GNU) insist on that space.

Comment: @Shawn GNU does a lot of things that are utterly bizarre. They're an outlier.

Comment: You actually don't need to store anything -- you can do it in-place by checking the last letter, if it's 'n', output the number, if it's not 'n', throw it away.

Answer (score 1):

If ends in 'n' means the last letter than this would do.

`char TTablaFrases[5][80]` degrades to a `char *TTablaFrases[80]` when passed to a function, so you need to pass in the length of your table or use a sentinel (empty string aka '\0') to signify end of the table.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef char  TTablaFrases[5][80]; //una tabla de 10 frases

int FraseAcabadaEnN(TTablaFrases tabla) {
    for(size_t i = 0; *tabla[i]; i++) {
        size_t l = strlen(tabla[i]);
        if(tabla[i][l-1] == 'n')
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

int main(void) {
    TTablaFrases miTabla;
    strcpy(miTabla[0], "First phrase");
    strcpy(miTabla[1], "Second phrase n");
    strcpy(miTabla[2], "Third phrase");
    miTabla[3][0] = '\0';
    int i = FraseAcabadaEnN(miTabla);
    if(i >= 0)
        printf("%s\n", miTabla[i]);
}
```

and it prints:

```
Second phrase n
```

Comment: My pleasure.  It's implied when you accept / upvote an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I’m trying to understand the code and I have two questions: 1) why do you have to pass sizeof(miTabla) / sizeof(*miTabla) to the function? I mean why the two values. And 2) could you explain the if condition. Why is it using a size_t and comparing with n?

Comment: 1) See 2nd paragraph.  2) In c an expression is true if not zero so `if(l &&` is just a shortcut for writing `if(l > 0 &&` (as `size_t` is unsigned so it cannot be negative).  This to ensure that we don't run the 2nd part (`&&` has a feature called short-circuit so it only evaluates the right side if needed) `tabla[i][l-1] == 'n'` if `l == 0` as that would out of bounds for the array.  Using `size_t` as that is the type of the value returned by  `strlen()` and `sizeof()`.  Did that answer your questions?

Comment: `{Intemission... Why not try an ice-cream from our confectionary counter during this break...}` Unh... Allan... The array has 5 'rows', but only 3 are initialised... If there were no 'n' to be found in the first 3 rows, you'd be off in UB land.... "It's always something, isn't it?" `:-)`

Comment: Yes! It’s clear now! Thanks!

Comment: @Fe2OS3 The fix is either adjust the size of the array to match the data, or use the sentinel idea.  I did the latter as it preserves the original signature of the function.

Answer (score 0):

The function needs to loop over each *row* of the array, skipping rows that contain no information.
For rows that contain text, the last character is tested as being the letter 'n'.
The index of the first row that meets this criteria is returned to the caller,
else an *impossible* value is returned to indicate no rows matched the criteria.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// incorrect comments are disturbing
typedef char TTablaFrases[5][80]; // una tabla de frases

int FraseAcabadaEnN( TTablaFrases tabla ) {

    // check each 'entry'
    for( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof *tabla/sizeof *tabla[0]; i++ )

        // is there something to check on this entry?
        if( tabla[i][0] )

            // is the last character 'n'?
            if( tabla[i][ strlen( tabla[i] ) - 1 ] == 'n' )

                // return this table index
                return i;

    // return impossible 'index' indicating "not found"
    return -1;
}

int main() {
    TTablaFrases miTabla = { 0 }; // ALWAYS intialise ALL variables

    strcpy( miTabla[0], "First phrase" );
    strcpy( miTabla[3], "Second phrase n" ); // NOTE! putting into array element #3
    strcpy( miTabla[2], "Third phrase" );

    int i = FraseAcabadaEnN( miTabla );
    if( i >= 0 )
        printf( "Elem #%d - %s\n", i, miTabla[i] );

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Elem #3 - Second phrase n
```

**ALWAYS** initialise variables. Uninitialised variables are a source of many bugs.